# How to set user/group/mode for directory created with `install -D`

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

When installing a file with the `-D` option to include creation of parent directories, how do you specify the user, group, and mode to use for the created directories? This is in the context of an RPM spec file, e.g.:

```
%install
install -m 750 -D %{_sourcedir}some/path/functions.sh %{buildroot}/opt/some/path/functions.sh

%files
%defattr(640, root, somegroup, 750)
/opt/some/path/functions.sh
```

The directory structure `some/path` is created under `/opt`, and `functions.sh` is correctly placed in the new directory, with the correct permissions and owner. However, both `some` and `path` directories are created with mode `755`, owner `root`, and group `root` (note, I am installing as `root`).

How can I update the `install` command to ensure that the parent directories are created with mode `750`, owner `root`, and group `somegroup`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Need to include the directories within the `%files` directive, and mark them as `%dir`, e.g. ...

```
%files
%defattr(640, root, somegroup, 750)
%dir /opt/some/path
/opt/some/path/functions.sh
```